# Error using JPA SELECT NEW with Timestamp on constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following JPA Query:

```
SELECT NEW test.vo.HappyVO(o.acid, o.dest, o.dep, o.time) FROM HappyTable1 o
```

My HappyVO has the following constructor:

```
public HappyVO(String a, String b, String c, java.sql.Timestamp e)
```

When i run this query i get the following error:

```
 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [test.vo.HappyVO]
```

if i change the constructor to

```
public HappyVO(String a, String b, String c, Object e)
```

the error doesn't occur and variable *e* is an instance of java.sql.Timestamp

Forgot to mention i'm using a MySQL database, and the column is of type timestamp and declared type of the time field in HappyTable1 is java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: What's the declared type of `HappyTable1.time`? If it's java.util.Date, your constructor should use the same type.

Comment: It's java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 6):

It looks a lot like this known Hibernate bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4179

The suggested workaround is to use a Date type in your POJO constructor.